# 'getaddrinfo()' function, it returns IP address from 'etc\hosts' file only ...?

Tags: windows, networking, dns, getaddrinfo

I have dual stack Windows m/c, with IPv4 and IPv6 address.
The `etc\hosts` contains only IPv4 address of that hostname.
So whenever I call `getaddrinfo()` function, it returns IP address from `etc\hosts` file (i.e IPv4 only not IPv6 address).

`ipconfig` command shows both IPv4 as well as IPv6 address.

How to configure `getaddrinfo()` function to always return IPs from DNS rather than `etc\hosts` file ?
Any other way to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

Name resolution is entirely independent from address configuration. Unless the name resolver learns of the IPv6 address (by inclusion in the *hosts* file, or a DNS entry, or mDNS, or...), it cannot return the address.